# MVC 5 JQuery Validate and unobtrusive - Unable to get property 'normalizer' of undefined or null reference

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-5, unobtrusive-validation

I'm using jquery.validate.min.js and
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js in an MVC 5 app.

I'm trying to validate in a modal form. The Fields are not model bound.
I’m having an issue with unobtrusive validation.
I get this error.

Unhandled exception at line 779, column 4 in http://localhost:60667/Scripts/jquery.validate.js
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'normalizer' of undefined or null reference.

It occurs in the ChartEditModal.

```
   function OnChartSave()
   {
         if (OnChartSave.caller == null) return false;

         // Reset jQuery Validate's internals (resets the inputs)
         formValidator.resetForm();

         if (!formValidator.element("#TitleDetail")) return;
   }

   $(document).ready(function ()
   {
         // Initialise form validator
         formValidator = $("#dashboardForm").validate();

         $("#TitleDetail").rules("add",
         {
                required: true,
                messages: { required: "A title must must be specified" }
         });
   });
```

The markup:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group preventWrappingClass">
       @Html.Label("Title", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4 labelForStyling" })
       <div class="col-md-12">
          @Html.Editor("TitleDetail", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control pull-left", @id = "TitleDetail" } })
          @Html.ValidationMessage("TitleDetail", "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And the Parent is

```
<form id="dashboardForm">
```

And in the parent script.

```
   var formValidator = null;
```

I’ve tried re-arranging the order of the script references, removing some, trying with Layout = null.

And

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Chart.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/utils.js")
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/Chart.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Site.js"></script>
```

Edge and chrome give me :

"Cannot read jquery.validate.js:779 property 'normalizer' of undefined
at $.validator.check

Any ideas please?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same error with jquery validate and Telerik checkboxgroup and radiogroup controls. Turns out it's all about the name attribute. If the name attribute is missing from an input or placed on the wrong html tag (example UL), this is the result. Hope it can help someone in the future.